Is it possible to add an audio stream to an already existing audio and video stream that is being recorded by MediaRecorder?
I am building an interview application where I am interrogated by an AI and I have to answer questions. The interview is recorded using MediaRecorder. The problem is that the audio that is generated by Whisper AI is not recorded. I tried combining the streams but then the recording stops once the Whisper audio is added to the stream.
The flow is like this:

The recording starts as soon as the interview starts
Whisper audio is played with the first question
I answer the question
2nd question etc.

I want all the audio recorded (from my mic and the Whisper audio).
Currently my working code looks like this (without combining the streams):
  let chunkIndex = 0
  const handleInterviewStart = async() => {
    setInterviewStarted(true)

    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: { deviceId: selectedVideoDeviceId ? { exact: selectedVideoDeviceId } : undefined },
        audio: { deviceId: selectedAudioDeviceId ? { exact: selectedAudioDeviceId } : undefined }
      });

      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
          uploadChunk(event.data, chunkIndex, false)
          chunkIndex += 1
      };
      mediaRecorder.start(5000);
      setInterviewRecorder(mediaRecorder);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error starting interview recording:', error);
    }

    console.log('INIT MESSAGE: ', initMessage)
    await transcribeAndComplete(true)
  }

const playSpeech = async (response) => {
    try {
      // Create a new audio element
      const audio = new Audio()

      // Set the audio source to the API route URL with text as a query parameter
      audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(await response.blob())
      
      audio.play()
    } catch (error) {
       console.error("Error playing speech:", error)
    }
 }

Anyone knows how to achieve this?
